# Are the periods in Revelation a single period of 3 and 1/2 years or something else?

Tags: revelation

Do the periods in Revelation refer to the same period of 3 and 1/2 years, multiple periods of 3 1/2 years, two halves of a 7 year period, or something else?

Is there anything in the text to suggest the multiple references are NOT to a single 3 and 1/2 year period?

The references are:

- 42 Months - Rev 11:2, Rev 13:5
- 1260 days - Rev 11:3, Rev 12:6
- time, times and half a time - Rev 12:14 (also Dan 7:25, Dan 12:7)

I am interested foremost in any clues in Revelation, and secondarily other references as they may relate to Revelation.

I am familiar with the arguments regarding the 70th week of Daniel in Daniel 9, 
but is there anything else to suggest a period other than 3 1/2 years?

**I am trying to avoid** the typical arguments that flow from a Darbyian/Dispensational view applied as a hermeneutic and discover what the text implies on its own. I am fairly familiar with this view, but would be appreciate any arguments based on the text itself.

**Note:** I see that my question was biased toward a view, namely that the period was a single period. I have edited in order to remove initial bias and open the question up to more input.

Comment: Are you also looking for anywhere else in Scripture (besides in Revelation and Daniel) when a 3-1/2 year stretch of time is mentioned, in those ways or any other?

Comment: I haven't, but if there is reason to believe the period in Revelation is a reference to something else, or something else in scripture sheds light on the period in Revelation, I'm interested. I know Revelation uses the OT a great deal, so this makes sense to me. Of course, there is the "seven" that permeates all of the OT, but I'd prefer to entertain arguments that are more specific rather than general. The "time, times, and half a time" is such a specific construction it seems likely to me this is the reference the apostle is pointing to.

Comment: I don't know if this is the type of answer you're looking for, so here's a comment for now. These 3-1/2 years could be references to the 3-1/2 years of drought Elijah had, shown via Luke 4:25 "But I tell you of a truth, many widows were in Israel in the days of Elias, when the heaven was shut up three years and six months, when great famine was throughout all the land;"  and also with James 5:17 "17 Elias was a man subject to like passions as we are, and he prayed earnestly that it might not rain: and it rained not on the earth by the space of three years and six months.".

Comment: @John Martin - That is interesting. Worth looking into. Thanks.

Comment: @DonJewett-Based on your additional comments I will delete my post. I'm not "Dispensational", but I do believe the text must be translated literally when the Context is literal. My caution to you is if you are trying to extract 'meaning' outside of context, you will find it-but it will lead you nowhere. The numbers have been translated; the task is to make "God's sense" out of them. My suggestion is this: understand the overall purpose God has for using them, and you will understand how they are to be used.

Comment: @user2479 - Fair enough. I am actually trying to extract meaning from the context, as opposed to preconceptions. I agree that making "God's sense" out of them is the ultimate objective! I have serious doubts about the Dispensational view, and am trying to find out what can be established from the text. In my view, the text should determine the theological view rather than the other way around. I know this particular issue is tricky, but BH seems like the right place to try.

Comment: @user2479 - btw - I thought your comment about the length of the periods possibly being different was intriguing.

Comment: @DonJewett-I believe both Covenant and Dispensational Theologies are inadequate in interpreting Revelations: 1)Covenant Theology is only concerned w/Law v Grace, it makes absolute nonsense in describing Israel's relationship w/God in the last days.2) Dispensationalism acknowledges the obvious, yet is married to "Literalism", in which symbology is devoid of meaning, or worse, assigned 'meaning' based on literal interpretation of figurative expressions.

Comment: @DonJewitt-I am a futurist/historicist, although not in the classical sense of historicism. I believe in a future return of Christ, as Messiah to Israel and as ruler and King over all the earth for the Millenial Reign. I am a 'post tribulation' rapture, as I believe the tribulation(not the final consumation) is here now, hence the 'historicist'. I DO accept the "Gap Theory"(ie:Final Week of Daniel being fulfilled before the return of Christ), the reason I do is because God gave 1 week to the world while Noah was gathering the animals in the Ark-a prefigurement of the last days.

Comment: @DonJewitt(final thoughts) I believe you must interpret Revelations "literally" when the context is literal, and "figuratively" when the context is figurative, but you can't mix the two in the same interpretation. An example is: The Catholic Church is the Great Harlot, because it 'rests' on seven literal hills in figurative 'Rome'. Either the 'Mountains' mean something other than physical mountains, or the Great Harlot is a woman with a Great Big Butt-you can't 'mix' literal and figurative to suit your interpretation, any more than you can mix cotton and wool, or wheat and barley.

Comment: @user2479: I think you have a major presuppositional flaw (and unsustainable principle) when you say "you can't mix the two [literal and figurative] in the same interpretation." For example, Jn 10:9 Christ says "I am the door." By your principle, either Christ is not literally referring to Himself because both He and the door are to be taken figuratively, or Christ is literally some (likely wooden) obstruction blocking an entry way because both are to be taken literally. All figurative language grounds to something literal, and cannot have meaning without a relation to something literal.

Comment: @ScottS-Christ transends both literal and figurative-He IS God-therefore beyond our human understanding: He is beyond a human metaphor explaining His existence. Therefore, in the context of that sentance we are not merely looking at Christ through the eyes of the flesh(as if we could attach hinges to Him and hang him on a mullion) but the reality of the figurative expression is that we cannot "access" the Kingdom of Heaven without Him: they are 2 Spiritual Realities expressed through a "Figurative Statement".

Comment: @ScottS(I hope I'm not boring you....) I define "Figurative" as an expression that describes another reality. So you are Correct in identifying "door" as the literal component being compared(He is not a 'chair', 'table', 'window', etc), and yet the truth of the statement is not understood by the composition of doors, but what they represent(the letting in and out). Therefore "door"= "Access" in this statement, rather than something we would search for in the building materials section at Home Depot.

Comment: @user2479: I could say much in reply, but I'll limit myself to that which helps you grasp my point (which I think you missed). In the figurative statement "I am the door" the "I" refers literally to the Person of Christ, while the door is figuratively understood essentially as you noted. Likewise, it can be so that "The Great Harlot" can be a figurative reference to some "entity" while the seven mountains are literal. The two are always mixed somehow, so that one can know something about the literal based off the figurative, or about the figurative, based off the literal.

Comment: @user2479: And let me clarify, I am not necessarily arguing for any particular interpretation of Harlot, but merely pointing out that a presupposition that literal and figurative _don't mix_ is invalid in interpreting the text.

Comment: @ScottS-I totally understand your point-theoretically, you can 'mix' literal and figurative. But God doesn't mix 'literal' and 'figurative', any more than He mixes wheat and barley, or wool and cotton. Why? Because it creates confusion-and God is NOT the Author of confusion. He is communicating a message to His Church, a message He doesn't want to reveal to His enemy. To indiscriminately mix figurative and literal contexts, confuses His saints, and allows anyone to present any sort of meaning to His Words-contrary to Rev. 22:18-19.

Comment: @user2479: (I'm not alerted to your tag of me; maybe the hyphen after the name is messing it up). I think we are talking past each other. I agree "door" = "access" (figurative connotation). "I am the door" (figurative statement). The "I" is a literal Person (Christ). The concept of "door" is a literal idea with many connotations to it, the "access" idea here the key point. The concept of "access" is itself a literal idea. The result of this access, "he will be saved ..." (Jn 10:9) is a literal result. My point is, one (even God) cannot have a "purely" figurative statement that has any meaning.

Comment: @ScottS I will attempt to put some definitions to terms which hopefully will help clarify the meanings. A "Literal" interpretation is the historical/grammatical usage of the word. A "door", historically/grammatically is an object made of some dense material, hung on hinges which would allow it to be "opened or closed". A "door of opportunity" does not qualify as the literal meaning; whereas an 'opportunity' can open or close, if I sent you to purchase a door-would you come back with an opportunity? Figurative is representitive(X=A).

Comment: @ScottS (cont.)To say you are "Born Again" does not mean you have re-gestated through your mother's womb. Nicodemus was using the historical/grammatical interpretation of the day and Jesus reproved him. Therefore "Born Again" doesn't mean 're-pass through your mother's womb' but regeneration. It is a reality-just not the 'reality' that is assigned the historical/grammatical meaning of the words. In summary, if we are talking about how the language is meant to be interpreted in it's normal grammatical usage, it's Literal. If the words are representitive of another reality, it's figurative.

Comment: @user2479: (I got notified, thanks.) I can see we define things differently. I would include "figurative" within the realm of the historical/grammatical interpretation, not outside of it. I will not debate more here (since a comment thread is not the best place for it).

Comment: @ScottS Fair enough, there is enough debate out there about this issue to circumnavigate the globe. But this explains my hermeneutic for interpreting Revelations: it doesn't follow a "Dispensational" theme, nor a "Covenant" theme. Rather, it follows the language in the context is is meant: Literally and Figuratively, under the rules I have described.

Comment: From a mild partial preterists viewpoint, why should they be? The question,  don't know if BH.SE could answer, is if the "time, times, and half a time" is a particularly unique representation of a 3 1/2 year interval, or if it's a common expression.  The 7 year cycle of Jewish calendar is ample support for the non-uniqueness of a 3 1/2 year period.  It's reoccurrance in various places (Elijah) helps support this. The simple fact that modern popular eschatologies says nothing, but you can be sure at least many would not want to entertain the notion to say the least.  Doesn't mean it isnt valid.

Comment: Another interesting facet of the Jewish calendar is the inclusion of an occasional 13th month.  This could more than account for periods of 1290 days, and the others by the inclusion of the leap month in one of those 3 1/2 years.  looked at this way,  without further study, seems like it could possibly be more support for the thought.

Comment: I believe it to be the same time period, from when the abomination of desolation is set up, 
the people in Judea flees (Matt 24), 
Antichrist rule from that point (Rev 13)
2 Witness (Rev 11) they are killed by the antichrist himself, after 3/12 they are resurrected (the antichrists rule is over, Babylon will fall and then the wrath of God follows)

Comment: @ Lucian   Here is another ref.  - Revelation 11:2, 3  But as for the courtyard that is outside the temple sanctuary, leave it out and do not measure it, because it has been given to the nations, and they will trample the holy city underfoot for 42 months. 3 I will cause my two witnesses to prophesy for 1,260 days dressed in sackcloth.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## There is Evidence for Two Periods without Reference to Dan 9

### Introductory Comments

- **A Commitment**: To abide by the parameters you have set (at least as I understand them), specifically avoiding in the main argument reference to Daniel 9 and the 70th week. Of course, it is always dangerous to purposefully "exclude" any part of God's Revelation in coming to understand the meaning of texts. That exclusion may hold the one key to a correct interpretation. However, I believe in this case your question can be answered without it (just perhaps not in full detail).
- **A Disclaimer**: I am a Dispensationalist.
- **A Clarification**: The “Darbian/Dispensational view” is not itself “applied as a hermeneutic,” but rather is a theology that derives from a grammatical-historical hermeneutic, a theology that works very diligently to have conclusions “based on the text itself.” I hope to demonstrate some of that here, as such is the hermeneutic that I will be following.
- **Some Assumptions**: We will assume here (as you have, and I think rightly) that the “time and times and half a time” are a reference to 3 1/2 years just as the other numerical references are, and that such numbers are to be taken literally (there are hermeneutics that do not take numbers literally). Additionally, it is assumed here that the trumpet soundings of Revelation are sequential, one following the other (not all hold to this either)—this is actually demonstrated by other factors in the argument below, but to avoid need of proving it more fully, it will be assumed. Finally, the view taken here is a futurist view, that the events are describing things not only future at the time of their being prophesied, but still future as of the posting of this answer (other hermeneutics will derive a different conclusion on this as well).
- **Of the translation**: All quoted text is from NKJV (unless otherwise noted), and emphasized text or summarized concepts is deemed more relevant to the question at hand.

### The Argument

**Daniel 7**

*Summary of Critical Points to the Question*

The fourth beast (Dan 7:7) was the fourth and final kingdom (7:23) prophesied to Daniel. From within this fourth kingdom were 10 horns (7:8) which were kings (7:24), 3 of which are removed or subdued before **a little horn (king)** who rises (7:8, 20, 24). This little horn is most characterized by the fact that he has “a **mouth speaking pompous words**” (7:8; cf. v.11, 20, 25). It is also this little horn that “was **making war against the saints, and prevailing against them**,” (7:21) for a period of “**a time and times and half a time**” (7:25), which prevailing lasts only “**until** the Ancient of Days came” (7:22).

*Commentary on Timing*

This information locates the 3 1/2 years as the final time up to the coming of the Ancient of Days, a period in which the saints are losing the battle here on earth. **This then is the final 3 1/2 years before God takes direct rule back.**

---

**Daniel 11-12**

*Summary of Critical Points to the Question*

The position of “king of the North” changes hands twice rapidly in Dan 11:19-21, the second time being taken by “**a vile person**” (11:21), who then goes against the long time foe of the (position of the) king of the North, “the king of the South,” and the North prevails (11:25). Of this new vile person that **is now the king of the North** it is said that “his heart shall be moved against the holy covenant” (11:28-29) and favor those who forsake it (11:30, 32), and **he defiles the sanctuary, stops sacrifices, and places the abomination of desolation there** (11:31), and those “**who know their God … shall fall by sword and flame, by captivity and plundering**” (11:33), all of which “**until** the time of **the end**,” so only for “the **appointed time**” (11:35). During this time this king “**shall exalt and magnify himself** above every god, shall **speak blasphemies against the God of gods**, and shall prosper till the wrath has been accomplished” (11:36). Forsaking God, exalting self, but honoring a new unknown god (11:37-38). **When it is time for this king’s end** (11:45), “**At that time** Michael shall stand up, the great prince who stands watch over the sons of your [Daniel’s] people … and **at that time** your people shall be delivered” (12:1), but immediately before Michael’s standing and delivering, even up “to that time” is “**a time of trouble** such as never was since there was a nation” (12:1), which refers back to that period of their falling before the end (11:33-35). One asks **how long is this period of trouble** until the time Michael stands at the end (12:6), to which the reply is “**a time, times, and half a time**.” The trouble **only finishing** once it is true that “**the power of the holy people has been completely shattered**” (12:7).

[NOTE: Two other time measures are given following these verses: (1) “from the time that the daily sacrifice is taken away, and the abomination of desolation is set up” is “one thousand two hundred and ninety days” (12:11), and (2) “Blessed is he who waits, and comes to the one thousand three hundred and thirty-five days” (12:12). Answering the relation of these times to the 3 1/2 years is outside the scope of this question, but it is obvious that they are not referring to the exact same 1260 days, though overlap is certainly occurring.]

*Commentary on Timing*

[Brief Excursus: It seems quite likely to me that this vile person who has the two previous kings of the North die before his ascension, and the one king of the South he takes out himself, are the 3 kings that fall because of him. Of course only the final of the three is flatly stated to be subdued by this vile person, but the rather oblique language used for the fall of the first king of the North, along with the short reign of the second who also has his death rather obliquely referred to could well relate to the “intrigue” of how the vile person seizes the kingdom (11:19-21).]

The identification of these three fallen kings in Dan 11 with those of Dan 7 need not be correct to still recognize that the identity of this new king of the North, the vile person, is the same as the “little horn” from Dan 7, for it is this king that has the same pompous spirit and words as that which so characterized the “little horn” king of Dan 7. Before the time of this vile person's end when Michael is standing to deliver Daniel’s people is this great time of trouble, that spans *from* the abomination of desolation (11:31) *to* the end (11:35, 45). A period we are told is this 3 1/2 years (12:7).

This information locates the 3 1/2 years of trouble being from the abomination of desolation up to the end time of the standing of Michael the great prince, a period in which those who know their God are losing the battle here on earth. **This is then the same time as Dan 7 refers to, the time right before God takes direct rule back.**

---

**Revelation 11:1-14 (some notations back to 9)**

*Summary of Critical Points to the Question*

The temple of God is present, with altar, and some are worshiping there, but the city itself is overrun by Gentiles, for the time of “**forty-two months**” (11:1-2), and two witnesses of God “prophesy **one thousand two hundred and sixty days**” (11:3). It is **not until** “they **finish their testimony**” that “the beast that ascends out of the bottomless pit **will make war against them**, overcome them, and kill them” (11:7). **After** they rise again in 3 1/2 days (11:9, 11), ascend to heaven (v.12), and an earthquake destroys part of the city (v.13), **the second woe is said to be past**, and the **third coming** soon (v.14).

*Commentary on Timing*

This information locates the 3 1/2 years during a time when the temple of God still exists and worshipers of God are gathering therein (i.e. the abomination of desolation is not set up), and in which the war against God’s people is not yet occurring, only beginning at the end of it. **This is then *NOT* the same 3 1/2 year time as that right before God is taking direct rule back.** Note that a confirmatory contextual clue to this is that these events are occurring within the 6th trumpet sounding, with one trumpet sounding to follow where other events are noted.

---

**Revelation 11:15-12:13**

*Summary of Critical Points to the Question*

**During the 7th trumpet sounding** (11:15), ***sometime* after** a woman’s child destined to rule all nations is “caught up to God and His throne,” (12:5) something compels the woman to flee “into the wilderness,” where God has made preparations for her sustenance that will last “o**ne thousand two hundred and sixty days**” (12:6), or “**a time and times and half**” (12:14). This time, however, does not occur until **after the dragon** who sought the child (12:4) **had been cast out from heaven** and down to the earth (12:9). This casting to earth is a “Woe to the inhabitants of the earth and the sea!” (12:12), and having been cast down to the earth, in his wrath **he persecutes the woman** (12:12-13). It is **then** that the woman takes her flight (12:6, 14). The dragon attempts to get her, but cannot, and instead goes “**to make war with the rest of her offspring, who keep the commandments of God and have the testimony of Jesus Christ**” (12:17).

*Commentary on Timing*

This information locates the beginning of the 3 1/2 years in conjunction with a time of persecution for the woman, from which she flees, but her offspring are instead made war with during this same time she is away in the wilderness. It is also located in the 7th trumpet sounding, after the events of Rev 11:1-14. **This is then the same time as that right before God is taking direct rule back as Dan 7 and 11-12.**

---

**Revelation 13**

*Summary of Critical Points to the Question*

The dragon gives power to a beast (13:1-2), one with “**a blasphemous name**” (v.1). A miraculous healing occurs to this beast, and many follow him because of it (13:3), worshiping both him and the dragon (13:4). This beast “was given a **mouth speaking great things and blasphemies**” and also “given authority to continue for **forty-two months**” (13:5). His blasphemies were “**against God … His name, His tabernacle, and those who dwell in heaven**” (13:6). The authority included “**to make war with the saints and to overcome them**” (13:7).

*Commentary on Timing*

This information locates the 3 1/2 years in conjunction with the beast’s speaking of blasphemies against God and making war against the saints, to the point of overcoming them. **This is the same language of Dan 7 and 11-12, and Rev 12, and thus is then the same time as that right before God is taking direct rule back.**

### The Conclusion: An Answer to Your Questions Exists

Yes, there is evidence derived from the context of the specified texts you noted which points to two separate periods, and thus there is something “in the text to suggest the multiple references are NOT to a single 3 and 1/2 year period.”

**First 3 1/2 Years**: Based on circumstances of Rev 11:1-14, the 3 1/2 years there (11:2, 3) precedes the abomination of the temple, and the making of war against the saints.

**Second 3 1/2 Years**: All other references (Dan 7:25; 12:7; Rev 12:6, 14; 13:5) are to a period of 3 1/2 years after the abomination, during which time the "little horn/vile person king of the North/beast empowered by the dragon" person speaks blasphemy and pompous words while making war with the saints.

The evidence noted does indicate the first period is not separated from the second period by much (if any), but does not clearly indicate (that I can tell) an immediate succession from one period to the next. So from the above argument your questions answer out as:

- “Do the periods in Revelation refer to the same period of 3 and 1/2 years?” **No**
- “Multiple periods of 3 1/2 years?” **Yes**
- “Two halves of a 7 year period?” **Possibly**
- “Or something else?” **Not likely**
- “Is there anything in the text to suggest the multiple references are NOT to a single 3 and 1/2 year period?” **Yes**

Comment: Thanks for your careful answer! I can see that it will take me a bit to work through and digest. Also, mention of your starting assumptions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Very detailed - thanks. Grammatical nuance also appears in Revelation 8:1 (please click [**here**](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/2798/921)) to indicate the apparent midpoint of the seven year period.

Comment: @Joseph: Thanks. That is assuming there is a grammatical nuance there at all. As the OP in that question notes, "some manuscripts have ὅτε," except it just so happens that the "some" is the "[majority](https://biblia.com/books/byzprsd/Re8)," so while the OP dismissed the fact that it could be ὅτε in all seven places, I would not be quick at all to dismiss such. For the record, I _generally_ hold with the minority of (modern) scholars that the majority text is the correct reading. If such is the correct reading, then nothing is indicated at 8:1 for the 7th different from the other six.

Answer (score 2):

I feel the best way to answer your question is by "keeping the answer simple".I am a futurist so this question is answered from a futurist view My understanding is that the book of Revelation speaks of the last seven years of  planet earth

I have taken all quotes from NIV bible.

**How did i arrive at this conclusion ?**

In Revelation 11 we read,

> I was given a reed like a measuring rod and was told, “Go and measure
>   the temple of God and the altar, with its worshipers. 2 But exclude
>   the outer court; do not measure it, because it has been given to the
>   Gentiles. **They will trample on the holy city for 42 months. 3 And I
>   will appoint my two witnesses,and they will prophesy for 1,260
>   days,clothed in sackcloth.”**

When we look at the above two periods we see that each  equal three and a half years.

They will trample on the holy city for 42 months = **Three and a half years**

The two witnesses will prophesy for 1,260 days = **Three and a half years**

When we add these two periods of Three and a half years we get  = **Seven years**

The trampling of the holy city must take place **after** the "two witnesses" have given their testimony which leaves one to conclude that when the two witnesses give their testimony, that the times are more peaceful.This is the **first half of the seven.**

Now this **Seven** is the seven that is mentioned in chapter nine in the book of Daniel,

> 24 **“Seventy ‘sevens’** are decreed for your people and your holy
>   city to finish transgression, to put an end to sin, to atone for
>   wickedness, to bring in everlasting righteousness, to seal up vision
>   and prophecy and to anoint the Most Holy Place.
>   **“Know and understand this**: From the time the word goes out to restore and rebuild Jerusalem until the Anointed One,the ruler, comes,
>   there will be seven ‘sevens,’ and sixty-two ‘sevens.’ It will be
>   rebuilt with streets and a trench, but in times of trouble. 26 **After
>   the sixty-two ‘sevens,**’ the Anointed One will be put to death and
>   will have nothing. The people of **the ruler** who will come will
>   destroy the city and the sanctuary. The end will come like a flood:
>   War will continue until the end, and desolations have been decreed. 27
>   He will confirm a covenant with many for one **‘seven.’** **In the
>   middle of the** **‘seven’** he will put an end to sacrifice and
>   offering. And at the temple he will set up an abomination that causes
>   desolation, until the end that is decreed is poured out on him.

**How do we understand the covenant he will confirm for one seven ?**

After the the two witnesses have finished giving their testimony we read in Revelation 11:7,

> Now when they have finished their testimony, **the beast that comes up
>   from the Abyss** will attack them, and overpower and kill them. 8
>   Their bodies will lie in the public square of the great city—which is
>   figuratively called Sodom and Egypt—where also their Lord was
>   crucified. 9 **For three and a half days** men from every people,
>   tribe, language and nation will gaze on their bodies and refuse them
>   burial. 10 The inhabitants of the earth will gloat over them and will
>   celebrate by sending each other gifts, because these two prophets had
>   tormented those who live on the earth. [Please click here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/who-what-are-the-two-witnesses-in-revelation-11/7906#7906) to read
>   my answer about the two witnesses.

It is very important that the reader understands that the bodies of the two witnesses lie in the street of the city for three and a half days,and that this three and a half days really mean three and a half years or a  **time,times and half a time**.The days have been shortened from 1260 days to three and a half days.This is evident in the words of Jesus,for it is written in Matthew 24:15-22,

> 15 “So when you see standing in the holy place ‘the abomination that
>   causes desolation,’ spoken of through the prophet Daniel—let the
>   reader understand— 16 then let those who are in Judea flee to the
>   mountains. 17 Let no one on the housetop go down to take anything out
>   of the house. 18 Let no one in the field go back to get their cloak.
>   19 How dreadful it will be in those days for pregnant women and
>   nursing mothers!20 Pray that your flight will not take place in winter
>   or on the Sabbath. 21 For then there will be great distress, unequaled
>   from the beginning of the world until now—and never to be equaled
>   again.
>   **22 “If those days had not been cut short, no one would survive, but for the sake of the elect those days will be shortened.**

Time,times and half a time = **1 day,2 days and half a day** **= Three and one half days** that is in relation to the days being shortened,meaning the times have been shortened as referenced in Matthew 24:15-22

In relation to the holy city being trampled for 42 months or 1260 days or a time,times and half a time-the meaning here would be Three and one half years.

I will expand this further to enable the reader to fully understand the meaning of the times, months and days as written in Revelation.In Rev:17-12 we read,

> 12 “The ten horns you saw are ten kings who have not yet received a
>   kingdom, but who for **one hour** will receive authority as kings
>   along with the beast.

One hour is a unit of time.The Kings receive authority along with the beast for **one time** to make war against the people of God.

One hour to make war is not a lot of time, but when we view the one hour as one time,the interpretation reads,

The kings receive authority with the beast for **One year** =   **1 time ** which seems more credible than **1 hour**

I use this interpretation to understand Revelation 8:1 where we read,

> 8 When he opened the seventh seal, there was silence in heaven for
>   about **half an hour**.

The seventh seal being opened is the timing for the Kings and the beast to make war which is for one year, and during this "war campaign" there is silence from Heaven for, **Not half an hour **  - **but for half a year.**

The text would now read,

> 12 “The ten horns you saw are ten kings who have not yet received a
>   kingdom, but who for **One Year** will receive authority as kings
>   along with the beast.

And when the seventh seal is opened,the text would read,

> 8 When he opened the seventh seal, there was silence in heaven for
>   about **Half a Year**

As we have read,it is a terrible time for the people of God when the beast is released from the abyss.Before this there was a great outpouring of the spirit in the first half of the seven, [here](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Joel%202:28-32) but we know that the beast will be destroyed for it is written in Revelation 17:8,

> The beast, which you saw, once was, now is not, and yet will come up
>   out of the Abyss and go to its destruction. The inhabitants of the
>   earth whose names have not been written in the book of life from the
>   creation of the world will be astonished when they see the beast,
>   because it once was, now is not, and yet will come.

**Conclusion:**
The periods in Revelation consist of 2 periods of three and a half years.
The Ruler made a covenant for one seven with the people of God.This covenant is probably what we know as a "laying down of weapons of war". There is a great out-pouring of the spirit of God at this time (the first half of the seven), and many people begin to worship God and follow Jesus.In the middle of the seven the ruler breaks his word and again embarks on his "war campaign" and many people will be put to the sword [at this time .](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2020%3A4) Because of this "war campaign" against Gods'people we are reminded from scripture- The times,months, days will be shortened. [Matthew 24:22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2024:22)

> And at the temple he will set up an abomination that causes
>   desolation, **until the end that is decreed is poured out on him.**

Comment: Thanks for your input! However: You state the trampling must come after the witness give their testimony, but I don't see a substantive argument for it. This is the crux of my question. How do we know the trampling period and the witnessing period are not the same 3 1/2 years? Also, I specifically asked for answers without reference to Daniel 9. I'm suspicious of an interpretation which requires a 2000+ year gap to make it work.

Comment: @DonJewett- My view is that when Satan is locked in the abyss for one thousand years Rev 20:1-3, that this is a figurative period of time.Also this is the time when the 'two witnesses' give their testimony and they are NOT attacked and killed until the beast is released from the abyss Rev 11:7 (you must understand that the beast is Satan)There is a time of calm when the beast is locked in the abyss but when he is released "All Hell breaks loose" and this is when the trampling of Gods' people begins-the last three and one half years.It starts with the ending of God's testimony (cont)

Comment: @DonJewett- which is the killing of the "two witnesses" meaning the testimony of Jesus is dead ! (Two = Testimony).In short the first three and a half years is the time when the beast is in the abyss.There is no trampling at this time and this is evident because the two witnesses are still alive.Once the beast is released, the two witnesses are killed and the next period begins which is the trampling of Gods' people.

Comment: @DonJewett- it is worthwhile considering this question http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/6010/does-christ-return-to-heaven-after-the-thousand-year-reign-and-then-return-to-e Remember we are told of the "second coming of Christ" and this so called thousand year reign would mean that Christ comes back three times.Christ came once to earth and he will return once more-Not three times.

Answer (score 1):

The respective descriptions of time sequences (forty-two months, 1,260 days, and Time, Times & Half) appear to be synonymous. That is, parallels seem to appear when the end time is "rolled out," which appears to be Daniel's scroll that had been sealed until the end time ([Daniel 12:9](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%2012%3A9&version=NASB)). The end time of Revelation is therefore one scroll - please click **[here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/11663/921)**.

The diagram, *below*, attempts to illustrate these parallels, which appear upon the plain and normal reading of the text.  The references in red have no known placement because of lack of specificity in the text, and therefore appear as suggestions (and thus annotated with a question-mark).

[image]

Thus the scroll is "rolled out" and depicts various events, but not in chronological order. The appearance of characters (the beast, the Lamb, the woman, etc.) in the narrative provide reference points, which enable the reader to place the parallels in tandem with the time sequences.

In summary, the descriptions of the time sequences (forty-two months, 1,260 days, and Time, Times & Half) therefore appear synonymous in meaning with regard to extent of time. If these times sequences are synonymous in meaning, then the parallelism in the Revelation appears stronger.

In summary, the "end time" before the visible appearance of Jesus Christ to earth appears as a period of seven years comprised of two segments, which are 3.5 years each.

Answer (score 1):

A less direct answer is in Rev11. There the time of the 2 witness is 1260days. After that it is noted 'their dead bodies lay dead in the street three and one half days'. The time frame 3.5 days is exactly one half week. On the day per year principle this time REPRESENTS a time of 3.5 years. ONLY 1 instance of this exact time of 3.5 years is given in scripture. This was a time specified by our Lord. He had some special reason to call out this time. For no where in the O.T. Story is this exact time given. But Jesus calls it out:
But I tell you of a truth, many widows were in Israel in the days of Elias, when the heaven was shut up three years and six months, when great famine was throughout all the land; but unto none of them was Elias sent, save unto Sarepta, a city of Sidon, unto a woman that was a widow. [Luke 4:25-26]
Elias was a man subject to like passions as we are, and he prayed earnestly that it might not rain: and it rained not on the earth by the space of three years and six months. [James 5:17]
And it came to pass after many days, that the word of the Lord came to Elijah in the third year, saying, Go, shew thyself unto Ahab; and I will send rain upon the earth. [1 Kings 18:1]

Adding these REPRESENTATIVE years to the 1260 days gives a total trib time of 7 years.

Answer (score 1):

The overall content of the Book of Revelations borrows heavily from the Prophetic Books of the Old Covenant, so it would be rather forced or artificial to avoid acknowledging the existence of such parallelisms, especially in cases where the allusions are so obvious.

> [Revelation 11:2-3](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation_11:2-3&version=KJV&interface=print)  But the court which is without the temple leave out, and measure it not; for it is given unto the Gentiles: and the holy city shall they tread under foot **forty and two months**. And I will give power unto my two witnesses, and they shall prophesy **a thousand two hundred and threescore days**, clothed in sackcloth.
>
> [Revelation 12:6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation_12:6&version=KJV&interface=print)  And the woman fled into the wilderness, where she hath a place prepared of God, that they should feed her there **a thousand two hundred and threescore days**.
>
> [Revelation 12:14](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation_12:14&version=KJV&interface=print)  And to the woman were given two wings of a great eagle, that she might fly into the wilderness, into her place, where she is nourished for **a time, and times, and half a time**, from the face of the serpent.
>
> [Revelation 13:5](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation_13:5&version=KJV&interface=print)  And there was given unto him a mouth speaking great things and blasphemies; and power was given unto him to continue **forty and two months**.

The three time periods mentioned above (i.e., 3 <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> years, 42 months, and 1260 days) are all of the same length. The same figure (i.e., 3 <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub>) , but applied to days rather than years, is mentioned twice more in the same book :

> [Revelation 11:9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation_11:9&version=KJV&interface=print)  And they of the people and kindreds and tongues and nations shall see their dead bodies **three days and an half**, and shall not suffer their dead bodies to be put in graves.
>
> [Revelation 11:11](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation_11:11&version=KJV&interface=print)  And after **three days and an half** the Spirit of life from God entered into them, and they stood upon their feet; and great fear fell upon them which saw them.

The parallels to the Book of Daniel should the become obvious; thus, in the case of the 3 <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> years, we have :

> [Daniel 7:25](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel_7:25&version=KJV&interface=print)  And he shall speak great words against the most High, and shall wear out the saints of the most High, and think to change times and laws: and they shall be given into his hand until **a time and times and the dividing of time**.
>
> [Daniel 12:7](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel_12:7&version=KJV&interface=print)  And I heard the man clothed in linen, which was upon the waters of the river, when he held up his right hand and his left hand unto heaven, and sware by him that liveth for ever that it shall be for **a time, times, and an half**; and when he shall have accomplished to scatter the power of the holy people, all these things shall be finished.
>
> [Daniel 12:11-12](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel_12:11-12&version=KJV&interface=print)  And from the time that the daily sacrifice shall be taken away, and the abomination that maketh desolate set up, there shall be **a thousand two hundred and ninety days**. Blessed is he that waiteth, and cometh to the **thousand three hundred and five and thirty days**.

As for the 3 <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> days, we have :

> [Daniel 9:27](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel_9:27&version=KJV&interface=print)  And he shall confirm the covenant with many for one week: and **in the midst of the week** he shall cause the sacrifice and the oblation to cease, and for the overspreading of abominations he shall make it desolate, even until the consummation, and that determined shall be poured upon the desolate.

That the days of Daniel are to be interpreted as referring to years is based upon the fact that the Prophets Moses and Ezekiel have already done this in the previous generations :

> [Numbers 14:34](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers_14:34&version=KJV&interface=print)  After the number of the days in which ye searched the land, even **forty days, each day for a year**, shall ye bear your iniquities, even **forty years**, and ye shall know my breach of promise.
>
> [Ezekiel 4:5-6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezekiel_4:5-6&version=KJV&interface=print)  For I have laid upon thee **the years of their iniquity, according to the number of the days, three hundred and ninety days**: so shalt thou bear the iniquity of the house of Israel. And when thou hast accomplished them, lie again on thy right side, and thou shalt bear the iniquity of the house of Judah **forty days: I have appointed thee each day for a year**.

The 390 + 40 = 420 days of Ezekiel are a dead ringer for the 62 weeks of Daniel, since the latter amount to 434 days :

> [Daniel 9:25](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel_9:25&version=KJV&interface=print)  Know therefore and understand, that from the going forth of the commandment to restore and to build Jerusalem unto the Messiah the Prince shall be seven weeks, and **threescore and two weeks**: the street shall be built again, and the wall, even in troublous times.

Compare these figures to similar ones mentioned elsewhere in Scripture :

> [Genesis 15:13](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis_15:13&version=KJV&interface=print)  And he said unto Abram, Know of a surety that thy seed shall be a stranger in a land that is not theirs, and shall serve them; and they shall afflict them **four hundred years**.
>
> [Exodus 12:40-41](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus_12:40-41&version=KJV&interface=print)  Now the sojourning of the children of Israel, who dwelt in Egypt (the [LXX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint) adds *and in the land of Canaan*), was **four hundred and thirty years**. And it came to pass at the end of the **four hundred and thirty years**, even the selfsame day it came to pass, that all the hosts of the LORD went out from the land of Egypt.
>
> [1 Kings 6:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1_Kings_6:1&version=KJV&interface=print)  And it came to pass in the **four hundred and eightieth year** (the [LXX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint) reads **four hundred and fortieth year**) after the children of Israel were come out of the land of Egypt, in the fourth year of Solomon's reign over Israel, in the month Zif, which is the second month, that he began to build the house of the LORD.
>
> [Acts 7:6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts_7:6&version=KJV&interface=print)  And God spake on this wise, That his seed should sojourn in a strange land; and that they should bring them into bondage, and entreat them evil **four hundred years**.
>
> [Acts 13:20](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts_13:20&version=KJV&interface=print)  And after that he gave unto them judges about the space of **four hundred and fifty years**, until Samuel the prophet.
>
> [Galatians 3:17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Galatians_3:17&version=KJV&interface=print)  And this I say, that the covenant, that was confirmed before of God in Christ, the law, which was **four hundred and thirty years** after, cannot disannul, that it should make the promise of none effect.

**The Jerusalem Temple stood for 430 years**, which is what one obtains when adding together all the regnal years of the Kings of Jerusalem mentioned in the Books of Kings and Chronicles, starting with Solomon, and taking into account the fact that the Temple's foundation was laid in the very beginning of the latter's fourth year of reign ([1 Kings 6:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1_Kings_6:1&version=KJV&interface=print), quoted above).

When adding together all the time spans mentioned in the **Book of Judges**, one arrives at a total of about **450 years**, as mentioned by Paul in [Acts 13:20](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts_13:20&version=KJV&interface=print), quoted above.

Also, following [Ussher's interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ussher_chronology), there were **425 years** from Noah's Flood to Abraham's entrance into Canaan.

*I hope this small attempt to address the question will aid the reader gain more perspective into the topic at hand.*

Answer (score 0):

The most direct answer to your ??? Comes from 'And he said unto me, Unto two thousand and three hundred days; then shall the sanctuary be cleansed.' Dan8:13.
This clearly indicates the tribulation extends to a min of 6 years and some months.
https://www.scribd.com/doc/256431258/Detailed-Tribulation-Timeline
https://www.scribd.com/doc/186892468/Tribulation-Timeline

Comment: I'm very grateful for your participation here. [This site is a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423) Be sure to visit the [tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about this site. I think you can benefit a lot if you see the [kind of answers](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/520/3474) that this site is looking for. Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange!

Answer (score -1):

There is much in the first answer that I, as a futurist, agree with. There is a departure point; however, regarding Revelation 12. Chapters 4 through 11 are completely sequential AND they portray the entirety of the events from the first rapture to the return of Christ at the sounding of the 7th Trumpet. Rev 10:7 makes this clear. (Please note that I am fully persuaded that the 7 trumpets and the 7 bowls are the very same judgments: the one viewed from heaven; the other viewed from earth).

Revelation 12 is nearly all figurative and it is depicting the same order of events from the time of the first rapture to the time of the revelation of the Man of Sin (Antichrist) as Paul calls him. This is a key chapter in many respects but in regard to your question, there are a couple of things that ought to be noted. Having failed in trying to stop the rapture of the overcomers (12:5) Satan is simultaneously booted out of his strategic position in the heavenly regions by Michael and company. This dethroning to the earth sends him into a rage and he no longer attempts to hide his murderous agenda. He proudly reveals himself as Satan incarnate and he goes after the remaining offspring of the Woman. Note vss. 12:6 and 12:14. They both refer to the very same period of 3 1/2 years where "the Woman will be taken care of". In other words, the saints are protected during this 3 1/2 year period.

Now jump to 13:5 and note the 42 months. This is a different period from the 3 1/2 years mentioned above BUT it is immediately subsequent to it. The first 3 1/2 years in chapter 12 occurs and immediately following are the 3 1/2 years of 13:5. In chapter 12 the saints are protected, in chapter 13 they are conquered (the Holy Spirit is taken "out of the way"). IMO, this second 3 1/2 year period is the very same 3 1/2 years of Daniel 7:25. Therefore, there is a 7 year period from the time of the first rapture to the time of the final persecution of the tribulation saints. This period is NOT Daniel's 70th week.

It is also to be noted that this all occurs within the first 6 seal judgments. The 7th seal is not opened until all the tribulation saints are killed or captured. At the end of the 6th seal, all of these heroes and martyrs are raptured or resurrected into heaven (the first resurrection Ch. 20). THEN, the 7th seal is opened. This remaining seal and it's trumpets are Daniel's 70th week. A period of 7 years with the last 3 1/2 years known as the time of Jacob's Trouble.

If you were able to follow any of this, you will note that there will be a total of 14 years from the time of the first rapture of the overcomers until Jesus returns in power and glory on Mt. Olivet. The 7 year tribulation of the saints is NOT the same as Daniel's 70th week. There will be 7 years of trouble for the church and another 7 years of trouble for the Jews. The two periods are separate but subsequent.

If you are scratching your head about the "first rapture" we can discuss it but it is not entirely germane to your question.