# Does Revelation 13:5 allude to Daniel 9:27?

Tags: revelation, daniel

Daniel 9:27

> He will confirm a covenant with many for one ‘seven.’ In the middle of the ‘seven’ he will put an end to sacrifice and offering. And at the temple he will set up an abomination that causes desolation, until the end that is decreed is poured out on him.”

Revelation 13:5

> The beast was given a mouth to utter proud words and blasphemies and to exercise its authority for forty-two months.

forty-two months = three and half years

Does Revelation 13:5 allude to Daniel 9:27? Is this the middle of the great tribulation?

Comment: A [related](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8767) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two different times.  The "seven" of Daniel 9 is *one week* of time, or seven **days**, whereas the 42 *months* would be the equivalent of *180 weeks,* or 1260 days.

**The Prophetic Day-for-a-Year Time Formula**

> After the number of the days in which ye searched the land, even forty
> days, **each day for a year,** shall ye bear your iniquities, even forty
> years, and ye shall know my breach of promise. (Numbers 14:34, KJV)
>
> And when thou hast accomplished them, lie again on thy right side, and
> thou shalt bear the iniquity of the house of Judah forty days: **I have
> appointed thee each day for a year.** (Ezekiel 4:6, KJV)

Prophetic times are measured in ***days***, each of which will represent a year.  If a prophecy is given in months, each month will have 30 days and represent 30 years.  If a year is given, which would have 12 months of 30 days each, it would consist of a total of 360 days, thus representing 360 years.  These figures are supported by the fact that the 1260-day prophecy is also given as 42 months and as three and a half years.

**1260 Days**

> And the woman fled into the wilderness, where she hath a place
> prepared of God, that they should feed her there a thousand two
> hundred and threescore days. (Revelation 12:6, KJV)

**42 Months**

> And there was given unto him a mouth speaking great things and
> blasphemies; and power was given unto him to continue forty and two
> months. (Revelation 13:5, KJV)

**Three and a Half Times/Years**

> And to the woman were given two wings of a great eagle, that she might
> fly into the wilderness, into her place, where she is nourished for a
> time, and times, and half a time, from the face of the serpent.
> (Revelation 12:14, KJV)

Being two different times, they are two separate prophecies and have separate fulfillments.

**Fulfillment of the Seven Days/One Week**

The week which is split in half, into two parts each of 3.5 days, represents two 3.5-year periods of time immediately succeeding each other (they are part of the same "week"), following the Biblical day-for-year prophetic time formula that is given in Ezekiel 4:6 and Numbers 14:34.

This week starts with Jesus' ministry at his baptism, in AD 27.  He was "cut off" in the midst of the week, being crucified after three and a half years of ministry, in AD 30/31.  The second half of the week, ending in Ad 34 with the stoning of Stephen, signifying the final rejection of the Jews as God's chosen people, was a period of continued grace for the Israelite nation, and fulfilled Jesus' prophecy that they should be forgiven for 490 years (70 times 7--see Matthew 18:22).  Daniel's full prophecy, of which this last week was only a part, consisted of 70 weeks, or 490 years.

**Fulfillment of the 42 Months/1260 Years**

This prophecy of Revelation addresses the beast with seven heads and ten horns (see Rev. 12:3; 13:1; 17:3-9) that would try to destroy the man-child (Jesus) of the pure woman (God's church/people).  At the time of Christ, the Roman government authorities tried to destroy him.  All the babies in Bethlehem were killed in attempting to eradicate Jesus.  And it was the Romans who finally crucified him.  The civil powers of Rome gave way, however, to a new, religious power, still centered in Rome.  That power persecuted God's people, as the prophecy says, for 1260 years.  This time period began with the transfer of power to this newly formed entity in AD 538.  The 1260 years ended in 1798 when Napoleon's general, Louis-Alexandre Berthier, took its head of state captive (who later died in jail), and ended its reign of power over the nations of Europe and much of the world.

To fully understand the details of this prophecy requires careful study and close attention to the identifying marks for this beast power in Revelation--a study which goes beyond the scope of this answer.

**Conclusion**

Daniel 9:27 and Revelation 13:5 address two separate prophecies and do not refer to the same period of time, with the first addressing a single week, or seven years' prophetic time, and the second addressing forty-two months, or 1260 days/years of prophetic time.

Comment: Wonderful.  Do you have a site or a link where I can access your interpretations of end time prophesies?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially yes. Revelation is a overlay of Daniel.

However its root really is closer to the second beast.
But you are right.
I will add confirming the covenant is something Satan does, With a small people (Daniel 11:23). I believe he does so at the first half.

> Revelation 13:11-12 (kjv)
> 11 And I beheld another beast coming up out of the earth; and he had two horns like a lamb, and he spake as a dragon.
> 12 And he exerciseth all the power of the first beast before him, and causeth the earth and them which dwell therein to worship the
> first beast,   whose deadly wound was healed.

> Daniel 9:27 (kjv)
>
> 27 And he shall confirm the covenant with many for one week: and in
> the midst of the week he shall cause the sacrifice and the oblation to
> cease, and for the overspreading of abominations he shall make it
> desolate, even until the consummation, and that determined shall be
> poured upon the desolate.

Jesus made this part of His prophecy on The End.

> Matthew 24:15 When ye therefore shall see the abomination of
> desolation, spoken of by Daniel the prophet, stand in the holy place,
> (whoso readeth, let him understand:)

Overspreading of abominations would be better translated
the desolator comes in upon wings of desolation .
The entity Satan, causing desoliation.

Standing where he ought not. Is the correct translation.
Greek for this word "it" , is not fixed. It changes depending on subject.
Subject is Satan standing in Jerusalem telling the entire word he is God and Christ (Matthew 24:24).

The Basic meaning is:

That week is the week of years, Daniels final 70th.
Which Christ for The Elects Sake (Matthew 24:22-24)
shortened from 7 years to 5 months (Revelation 9:5).

Daniel 9:27 says the daily sacrifices stopped midst of the week.
Account the 5 months is essentially 2.5 Months.
At that marker point, Satan appears instead of Christ as anti-Christ.

> Revelation 13:13 And he doeth great wonders, so that he maketh fire
> come down from heaven on the earth in the sight of men,
>
> 14 And deceiveth them that dwell on the earth by the means of those
> miracles which he had power to do in the sight of the beast; saying to
> them that dwell on the earth, that they should make an image to the
> beast, which had the wound by a sword, and did live.

The fact he looks as the Lamb, says a lot
This will deceive most the worlds Christians for this cause, does the true worship to Christ cease. It is worded in Daniel as daily Oblation.
You'd have to update in your mind accounting that The Sacrifice for one and all time now, is Christ.

Because of Satan's miracles Christians in ignorance become the Whore, and take their worship to him.

> Revelation 17:16 And the ten horns which thou sawest upon the beast,
> these shall hate the whore, and shall make her desolate and naked, and
> shall eat her flesh, and burn her with fire.

This is called the falling away, in (2 Thessalonians 2).
Greek means Apostasy. To fall away from ones professed belief.

From the midst of the week formerly 3.5 years; now Satan has 2.5 months remaining at the end of which he turns violent against the two witnesses, and 3 and half days later they resurrect in the sight of all. Then Christ returns at that moment.

E.W.Bullinger in The Companion Bible has some interesting notes.
But I would caution you to apply the correction to the time Christ shortened it to. Revelation 9. This is overlooked by Bullinger.

> Verse 27 he shall confirm the covenant = make a firm covenant: i.e.
> the little horn will do this at the beginning of the last seven years.
> See note below on "one week". It may even be the beginning of the
> 2,300 days of Daniel 8:14 . Compare Daniel 11:21-24 .
>
> the covenant = a covenant.
>
> many = the many.
>
> one week . This is the last seven years which completes the "seventy"
> of Daniel 9:24 ; the time when action commences in connection with
> Daniel's "city" and "People" (i.e. Jerusalem and Israel). These have
> been in abeyance since Daniel 9:26 . Israel is " Lo-ammi" (= not my
> people, Hosea 1:9 , Hosea 1:10 ). For the present interval between,
> Daniel 9:26 and Daniel 9:27 , see Luke 4:18-20 ; Luke 21:24 . App-50 ;
> also App-63 . This fills the first half of the "week" (see Revelation
> 11:3-11 ).
>
> the midst of the week = the middle of the week (i.e. at the end of the
> first three and a half years).
>
> the sacrifice and the oblation to cease = sacrifice and oblation to
> cease. This is the action of "the little horn" (See Daniel 8:11 ,
> Daniel 8:12 , Daniel 8:13 ; Daniel 11:31 ; Daniel 12:11 ). This
> belongs to the time of the end, and will be accompanied by the setting
> up of the abomination mentioned below and by our Lord in Matthew 24:15
> . See App-89 and App-90 .
>
> for the overspreading of = on the wing, or battlement of; but Ginsburg
> suggests ' al kanno (instead of 'al kanaph) = in its stead [shall be]:
> i.e. in place of the daily sacrifice. Compare Daniel 11:7 .
>
> abominations he shall make it desolate = the abomination that maketh
> desolate. See App-90 . This is certainly future. See Matthew 24:15 .
> Our Lord tells us where it will stand "in the holy place": i.e. in the
> Temple at Jerusalem: and we have the same admonition to "understand"
> (compare verses: Daniel 9:23 , Daniel 9:25 , above). Antiochus, the
> type of "the little horn", defiled the sanctuary, but he did not
> destroy it. He cannot therefore be the fulfiller of this prophecy,
> though he foreshadowed him.
>
> abominations . Jehovah's name for an "idol", as being what he detests.
> Hebrew. shakaz = to be abominable. The "of" in this connection being
> the Genitive (of the Origin), App-17 .: i.e. which causes the
> desolation. Compare 2 Kings 23:13 .Isaiah 44:19 , &c. Daniel 12:11 is
> conclusive.
>
> until the consummation = unto a full end. The reference is to Isaiah
> 10:22 , Isaiah 10:23 .
>
> determined . See note on "the wall", Daniel 9:25 above.
>
> shall be poured upon = shall come pouring upon. For the fulfillment,
> compare Revelation 16:1 , Revelation 16:2 , Revelation 16:3 ,
> Revelation 16:4 , Revelation 16:8 , Revelation 16:10 , Revelation
> 16:12 , Revelation 16:17 .
>
> desolate = the causer of desolation. See Daniel 12:11 . Then the
> consummation of Daniel 9:24 will be fulfilled.

---

Here are some sources
that can help with finer points.

https://www.youtube.com/user/TheShepherdsChapel/playlists

https://mark13records.com/

https://www.youtube.com/user/JustThoughtsstudies/playlists

Answer (score 1):

**Do the 42 months in Revelation 13:5 allude to Daniel 9:27?**

The 42 months in Rev 13:5 is again mentioned in Rev 11:2 and it is the same as the 1260 days (Rev 11:3; 12:6) and the "time and times and half a time" (Rev 12:14). [time and times and half a time = 3½ years = 42 months = 42x30 = 1260 days] These time periods are all based on Daniel 7:25 and are always a time of persecution for God's people.

Daniel 9:27 describes the last "week" (seven years) awarded to Daniel's people (Dan 9:24). In the middle of that week, sacrifices are stopped. Consequently, it may be divided into two periods of 3½ years each. Therefore, in some interpretations, the "time and times and half a time" is equal to one of those periods of 3½ years.

In the [critical interpretation](https://revelationbyjesuschrist.com/490-years/), Daniel 9 describes the same crisis as the other prophecies in Daniel, namely the time of Antiochus IV in the middle of the second century B.C. Therefore, in this interpretation, the last week of Daniel 9, which is the crux of the prophecy, does include the "time and times and half a time" of Daniel 7:25.

In the [dispensational interpretation](https://revelationbyjesuschrist.com/dispensationalism/), Revelation 4:1 is the rapture and everything after this verse happen in the last seven years of Daniel 9. Therefore, in this interpretation, the 42 months (Rev 11:2; 13:5) are also part of those seven last years.

Therefore, and because the 42 months originates in Daniel 7:25, in both of these interpretations, **Daniel 7 describes the same crisis as Daniel 9:27**. There are similarities. As stated, some argue that the “time, times and a half” of Daniel 7:25 and 12:7 are mathematically equal to the 3½ years of the 490 years. And, in both Daniel 9 and the other chapters, sacrifices are caused to cease, and is destruction predicted. However, I would like to argue that there are substantial differences between Daniel 7 and 9.

In the analysis below, I assume that the prophecies in Daniel 2, 7, 8, and 11 are parallel. In other words, they describe the same crisis (the persecution of God's people by the Antichrist) and the same series of events:

- Daniel 2 provides a broad framework of 6 phases of the history of mankind but does not mention an Antichrist.
- Daniel 7 describes the same 6 phases but adds and puts the emphasis on the Antichrist (the eleventh horn-king) that will reign during the fifth phase (the "divided kingdom" of Daniel 2:41).
- Daniel 8 uses two beasts to describe two of those empires but puts the focus almost entirely on the Antichrist. The other details become fuzzy.
- Instead of beasts, Daniel 11 has a series of kings leading up to the Antichrist.

Whether the Antichrist is Antiochus IV, an end-time tyrant, or a historical superpower is not relevant here. The point is that those four prophecies describe the same crisis. For the following reasons, I propose that Daniel 9 describes a different crisis:

(1) While Daniel 9 describes the **490 years allocated to Israel**, the other prophecies deal with **all time** from the time of ancient Babylon until the return of Christ (Dan 7:27; Dan 2:38, 44).

(2) While Daniel 9 focuses exclusively on the **Jewish nation** (Dan 9:24), the other prophecies predict a series of **heathen empires** (e.g. Dan 2:38-40).

(3) While the other prophecies end with the return of Christ, the eternal kingdom (Dan 2:44-45; 7:18, 27), and the resurrection of the dead (Dan 12:2), Daniel 9 ends in chaos (Dan 9:27).

(4) In Daniel 9, the temple is destroyed (Dan 9:26). In Daniel 11, it is only profaned (Dan 11:31).

(5) In Daniel 9, the temple is first restored and then destroyed. It does not mention another restoration. In Daniel 8, the sequence is reversed: The temple is first desecrated and then restored (Dan 8:14).

(6) While Daniel 9 is a literal prophecy, the other prophecies use symbols. (I do not believe we need a year-day principle to interpret the 70 weeks as 490 years. Israel had weeks of years in which every seventh year was a Sabbath (Lev 25:2-4), and God made those years-weeks part of the covenant exile pattern (Lev 26:34-35; 43). Since we argue that the 70 weeks are an [extension of God's covenant with Israel](https://revelationbyjesuschrist.com/seventy-years/), they simply are 70 of those year-weeks.)

(7) In the other prophecies, the saints are persecuted (Dan 7:25), beasts symbolize empires (Dan 7:17), and the Antichrist is eventually destroyed (Dan 7:26). None of these are mentioned in Daniel 9.

(8) If the 2300 “evening morning” (Dan 8:14) are interpreted as 2300 sacrifices, of which there were two every day, thus interpreting the 2300 “evening morning” to 1150 days, it is equal to 3 years and 55 days and still not equal to anything in Daniel 9.

(9) In Daniel 9, we find the destruction of the city (Dan 9:26), the killing of the Messiah, and the 490 years, 49 years, 434 years, and 7 years. None of these are found in the other prophecies.

Conclusions

---

(1) While there are differences between the prophecies in Daniel 2, 7, 8, and 11, there is a significant similarity between these prophecies. But Daniel 9 seems to be very different.

(2) Daniel 9 does not describe the same crisis as the other prophecies in Daniel.

(3) This conclusion provides a challenge to both the critical and the dispensational interpretations.

(4) Many of the symbols in Daniel are carried forward into Revelation. For example, the Antichrist of Daniel and its reign of a time, times and ha;lf a time become the beast of Revelation (Rev 13:2), ruling for 42 months. But the prophecy of Daniel 9 does not seem to have a counterpart in Revelation.

For a further discussion, see [here](https://revelationbyjesuschrist.com/same-crisis/).